# How to find the input that maximize the Neural Network output in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I'm using Tensorflow (2.4) and Keras to build my neural network model. It takes two tensors as inputs and gives a scalar output. The network is already trained and, from now on, it has fixed weights. It is possible, given one of the two inputs, to find the value of the other input that maximise the output value?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes.

Lets call your network model `f`. It takes two inputs `x` and `y` and outputs `f(x, y)`. Then, assuming `x` and `f` are fixed, you can find the value `y*` that  maximize `f(x, y)` as follows:

calculate the gradient of `f` with respect to `y`. Then, there are two possibilities.

1. there exists stationary points. Just set `df/dy = 0` and solve for `y`. This gives the `y*` at which there is either a maximum or a minimum. Compute `f(x, y*)` to check weather `y*` gives a maximum or a minimum.
2. there are no stationary points (or there is no maximum). Here, you need to study where `f` decreases or increases if `y` varies. To do this, look for `df/dy > 0` (increases) and `df/dy < 0` (decreases). You will find that, asymptotically, the function increases. Simply take `y*=a`, where `a` is the closest value to such asymptote that you can take (given your data type precision).